# ¿Como abrir la app de twitter desde un activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

Con un boton en una activity, necesito abrir la app de Twitter. Buscando, encontre este codigo, al cual le agregue un par de lineas, pero no logro que funcione.

Al oprimir el boton en el activity unicamente parpadea la pantalla pero no pasa nada, me podrian indicar por favor como lo corrijo o si existe una mejor forma de hacer lo que necesito. gracias

El codigo que tengo es este:

```
public void abrir_twitter(View view) {

    Intent intent = null;

    try {
        this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.Twitter.Android", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Twitter://user?user_id=24742040"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " Twitter no esta instalado en tu telefono ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegura escribir el protocolo en minúsculas, también el nombre de paquete `com.twitter.android`, reemplaza el valor de `USER_ID` en el siguiente acript :

```
Intent intent = null;
try{
   // Abre la app Twitter
   this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=<USER_ID>"));
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch () {
   //Si no se encuentra la app abre la versión web
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/USERNAME"));
}
```